# yocto: for some reason the populate_sdk task is being called when I build my image

Tags: dependencies, yocto, bitbake

when I run:
bitbake my-image

it runs the whole way through but also builds the nativesdk packages and then runs the my-image do_populate_sdk task. in other projects I've worked on, I had to explicitly run the populate_sdk task like this:

bitbake -c populate_sdk my-image

I have searched through all of my meta and I cannot find the place where this explicit dependency is stated. My question: What is the best way to find where a dependency for a task is setup?

also is there a way I can tell bitbake to not use this dependency? I know "bitbake -I " will remove a package dependency, but what about a task depend? how do I exclude the task depend. I tried to do this with

bitbake -I populate_sdk my-image

and used other combinations like "do_populate_sdk" to no avail...

I tried to use
bitbake -g my-image -u taskexp
to explore the dependencies, but searching for my-image.do_populate_sdk only shows the dependencies of the sdk.. I have found that "my-image.do_install" task depends upon the do_populate_sdk, which you would think would lead me to where someone added a dependency, but I can't seem to find where its done.

what would this look like? maybe:

```
do_install[depends] += "...populate_sdk...
```

I have searched for something like this but can't find it.

I have also run
bitbake -e my-image > file

and gone diving through this result, but I'm not sure it tells me where this is done.. anyhow its so big and populate_sdk is littered all through the file.

Any advice on narrowing down my search would be useful.

fyi our distro is based off of Seimens flex-os (previously Metor MEL), and we use lots of stuff including qt which bloats the build... I'm trying to build as little as possible and the SDK just makes everything take way longer...

Answer (score 0):

Someone added `inherit populate_sdk` to a bbappend file for `my-image.bb`. and of course in `populate_sdk.bbclass` we see `addtask populate_sdk after do_install before do_build`.